# Get 401 Get Report Failed when using Power BI Embed with SSAS On Prem

Tags: rest, powerbi, azure-devops-rest-api, powerbi-embedded

I am attempting to use the Embed Token that I obtained via the REST API websites to view my report in the microsoft embedded playground.

As I haven't been able to get my C# code to work in obtaining an embed token for Power BI I was able to utilize the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-reports-in-group#code-try-0) website to obtain one.

In doing so I then went to the [Microsoft Embedded playground](https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/home) and the [old one](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html?noRedirect=true&redirectFromNewPlayground=true) to test out my embedded report.  It failed to load, and in the old embedded playground I received this message.

```
> Json Object
{
  "message": "LoadReportFailed",
  "detailedMessage": "Get report failed",
  "errorCode": "401",
  "level": 6,
  "technicalDetails": {
    "requestId": "f30b3ae7-7f80-49b1-9479-5ea7aa6cbb1f"
  }
}
> Json Object
{
  "message": "LoadReportFailed",
  "detailedMessage": "Get report failed",
  "errorCode": "401",
  "level": 6,
  "technicalDetails": {
    "requestId": "f30b3ae7-7f80-49b1-9479-5ea7aa6cbb1f"
  }
}
```

After plugging in my embed token, tenant id, and embed url into the microsoft playground I expected to view my report instead of the error message I obtained above.

Screenshots of the power bi embedded playground errors:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Refer [Troubleshoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-troubleshoot) documentation and verify if all the details you're passing are correct

Comment: Can you please modify your question ? At the last you're mentioning that expecting to view dashboard and the same time you're mentioning about the report. Please Rephrase your question

Comment: Hi @KotanaSai I changed report to dashboard.  Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: @NutelleKing, I'm still confused that you mentioned that you changed the report to dashboard. But the snapshots, or REST API you're mentioning points out you're trying to embed a report.

Comment: Please go through docs and understand if you're embedding report or dashboard. As you pointed out the dashboard, i listed down the steps in my answer below. Let me know if you have any other questions

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to Embed a Dashboard.

1. For getting Dashboard Embed Url use the [Get Dashboard in Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/dashboards/get-dashboard-in-group) Rest API.
   If the dashboard is present in My workspace use the [Get Dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/dashboards/get-dashboard) Rest API.
2. For getting Embed Token use the [Dashboards GenerateTokenInGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/dashboards-generate-token-in-group) Rest API.
3. Token type Will be of `models.TokenType.Embed`.
4. You also require the dashboardId.

In the New [Playground](https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/), We can only embed a report and not dashboard.

In the [old Playground](https://pbie-playground-edog.azurewebsites.net/v2-demo/index.html), select Sample Dashboard from the samples and then embed the dashboard.

From the snapshot, you're using the Sample Report code editor instead of Sample Dashboard.

Comment: I apologize.  You are correct.  I am using a report and not a dashboard.  As that is the type I see in the workspace for this report.

Comment: THANK YOU @Kotana Sai!!!!  I have been messing with this for a week and your simple explanation got me across.  I created a dashboard and used your steps to test in the old playground and was able to get the dashboard to come across!

Now I may still have an issue with embedding reports but  I will move forward with the dashboard for now.

Comment: Sure, No worries. Let me know if you have any queries while embedding report. Happy to help :)

Comment: Embedding report will be almost similar, instead you use different Rest Apis to get the parameters